# How to justify choosing a distribution to model my data

Tags: r, distributions, data-visualization, modeling

I'm researching on stock returns and my final goal is to write around 70 pages on their distribution.

So far I have gathered data for several indices and companies using R and chosen some distributions to model my data with. For example; normal distribution, t distribution, skewed t, skewed normal, generalised lambda distribution etc...

The problem i'm having is justifying why I picked these distributions.

I thought of maybe plotting histograms of the best normal,t,lambda curve and then showing that the fit is good enough for us to use this model.

If that's true, how do I know if the curve is good enough to assume this.

And are there any other ways to justify choosing these distributions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question of which model to use for a given problem is an area of statistics unto itself, which is called *model selection*. Methods for this include AIC, cross-validation, and Bayesian model selection. Most introductory statistics textbooks will include material on model selection.

Comment: @HumzaAli Sure. If I answered your question to your satisfaction, you can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark under the voting arrows.